# Typescript error: "Cannot write file because it would overwrite input file"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript2.0

In our typescript 2.3.4 project(ionic2 & angular 4) using Visual Code, we are integrating third party "3D-Carousel". We are getting following errors:

**typescript error 
Cannot write file '/projectfolder/src/assets/js/3d-carousel/FWDUltimate3DCarousel.js' because it would overwrite input file.**

**typescript error 
Cannot write file '/projectfolder/src/assets/js/3d-carousel/init-3dcarousel.js' because it would overwrite input file.**

Following is the component code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import '../../../assets/js/3d-carousel/FWDUltimate3DCarousel.js';
import carousel3d from '../../../assets/js/3d-carousel/init-3dcarousel.js';

@Component({
   selector: 'command-3d-Carousel',
   templateUrl: 'Cmd3dCarouselWidget.html'
})
export class Cmd3dCarouselWidget {

constructor(public events: Events, private el: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone) {
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    carousel3d(this.el.nativeElement);
    });
}
}
```

Have checked all the suggestions like making "allowJs": true excluding the carousel Js files in tsconfig.json file. Updating typescript versions etc.The issue still persists.

The build process completes sometimes & the app runs(rarely once in a while), but most of the times the app crashes as a result of the above error's(i.e build process fails at "transpile started").

What can i do for fix it ? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

We did manage to solve the issue. Actually the way we were calling 3rd party libraries was wrong. Below is the code needed for the issue to fix:

**MyWidget.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var carouselComponent: any; 

@Component({
  selector: 'command-3d-Carousel',
  templateUrl: 'Cmd3dCarouselWidget.html'
})

export class Cmd3dCarouselWidget {

   constructor(public events: Events, private el: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone) {
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    carouselComponent(this.el.nativeElement);
    });
}
}
```

**init-3dcarousel.js**

```
var carouselComponent = function carousel3d(ele) {

carousel = new FWDUltimate3DCarousel({

    //required settings
    carouselHolderDivId: "myDiv",
    carouselDataListDivId: "carouselData",
    displayType: "fluidwidth",
    autoScale: "yes",
    carouselWidth: 940,
    carouselHeight: 538,
    ...
    ...
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Third party scripts for 3D Carousel -->
<script src="assets/js/FWDUltimate3DCarousel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/init-3dcarousel.js"></script>
```

What we observed was that the external js files were not being compiled correctly by typescript as we were using wrong approach for using 3rd party lib's in ionic app.